# Using Embedly api regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

Embedly has a great regex generator with which you can use to verfiy the correctnes of services urls(http://api.embed.ly/tools/generator). It generates javascript regexes, but unfortunately it does not generate c# regex expressions. As far as I know though, c# uses the same ECMA regex definition, and I should therefore be able to use the in C#

So what I would like to achieve is take the generated regex from the embdly site and just paste it into my c# code.

The javascript regex would look like this:

```
/http:\/\/(.*youtube\.com\/watch.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/v\/.*|youtu\.be\/.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/user\/.*#.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/.*#.*\/.*|picasaweb\.google\.com.*\/.*\/.*#.*|picasaweb\.google\.com.*\/lh\/photo\/.*|picasaweb\.google\.com.*\/.*\/.*)/i
```

and should match urls like:

http://picasaweb.google.com/westerek/LadakhDolinaMarkha?feat=featured#5497194022344000402
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVDc1uXda6Y&feature=related

What I have so far is the following:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(
      "[/http:\\/\\/(.*youtube\\.com\\/watch.*|.*\\.youtube\\.com\\/"+
      "v\\/.*|youtu\\.be\\/.*|.*\\.youtube\\.com\\/user\\/.*#.*|.*\\."+
      "youtube\\.com\\/.*#.*\\/.*|picasaweb\\.google\\.com.*\\/.*\\/"+
      ".*#.*|picasaweb\\.google\\.com.*\\/lh\\/photo\\/.*|picasaweb"+
      "\\.google\\.com.*\\/.*\\/.*)/i]",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
```

.. but this only gives me partial matches..

EDIT:
Solution: Just paste the embedly javascript regex expression into strEmbdlyRegex string in the following snippet.

```
    string strEmbdlyRegex = @"/http:\/\/(.*youtube\.com\/watch.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/v\/.*|youtu\.be\/.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/user\/.*#.*|.*\.youtube\.com\/.*#.*\/.*)/i";

string strRegx = strEmbdlyRegex.Remove(0, 1);
strRegx = strRegx.Remove(strRegx.IndexOf("("), 1);
strRegx = strRegx.Remove(strRegx.LastIndexOf(")/i"), 3);
strRegx = strRegx + "]";

regex = new Regex(
     strRegx,
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
    | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant
    | RegexOptions.ECMAScript
    | RegexOptions.Compiled
    );
```

Comment: That still isn't right.  For one thing, you're still adding that `]` to the end.  And you want to get rid of the leading `/` and the trailing `/i`, but the `(` and `)` are doing useful work; leave them in.

Comment: for those needing some code more (functional) code, I've created a project on codeplex: http://embedlynet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a bit more specific with your problem would help, but I appear to have it working (at least with your two test strings). You just need to clean up a few extraneous characters:

- Convert it to a literal string using the `@""` syntax (no escaping backslashes)
- Remove the `[/` from the beginning of the string
- Remove the `\i` from the end of the string
- Remove the `(` and `)` near the beginning and end of the string

Also, you probably don't need the [IgnorePatterWhitespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) option, and for a simple URL you probably don't need the [CultureInvariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) option either.

Lastly, there is a [RegexOptions.ECMAScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) option that allows you to pass in a /regex/i and have it be interpreted the same way JavaScript would handle it.

Comment: thanks! you understood me perfectly well, but I'll still try and be more specific next time. the @ is what got me!